# MongoDB select first result from documents meeting $in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, typeorm

I have this query in loop:

```
const currentDatas = await Promise.all(nearestStations.map(async (ns: any) => {
        return await this.stationCurrentDataRepo.findOne({
            where: { stationId: parseInt(ns[0], 10) },
            order: { date: 'DESC' },
        });
}));
```

I want to optimize that to don't make hundreds queries and get the data in one query.
What I need is to get newest record (sort by date) for every stationId from array of ids ($in array of ids). I need all data from every found document meeting what I specified above.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB this is done with aggregation pipeline and [$group operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group).